# "ERROR: Column does not exist" With an existing column

Tags: java, postgresql

I have the following java function. When I enter ingredientNaam as 'Banaan' it gives me the error:

> column does not exist.

However, the column does exist. I know this could have something to do with upper/lowercase, but because I need the `.get(0)` at the end of the statement, I don't know how I can fix this. Removing the `.get(0)` results in a return value list instead of an Ingredient, so I need this part.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

```
public Ingredient findByString(String ingredientNaam) {
    return selectIngredients("SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE ingredientnaam = "+ingredientNaam).get(0);
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE ingredientnaam = 'Banaan'` is this sql working ?

Comment: Consider adding the ingredient name as a parameter to a statement rather than catting it into your SQL. It will be safer and you won't need to worry about quoting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ingredient is a string, so you need to quote it. If you don't, it is considered as a column name.

```
public Ingredient findByString(String ingredientNaam) {
    return selectIngredients("SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE ingredientnaam = '"+ingredientNaam +"'").get(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for.